# Can anyone provide documentation for the 2011 chevy cruze eco grill shutters?

Tags: chevrolet, emissions, dtc, cruze

I'm trying to understand how they work and where the motor is since I am unable to get the plastic off the bottom of the grill to access them directly. Mine seem to move if I slowly torque them directly, but they are not actuating on their own and its constantly popping the P069E code from the Fuel Pump Control Module.

Comment: I don’t have the workshop manual, but you might find one - online possibly.

Answer (score 0):

> Active Grille Shutter:
>
> - How does the Active Grille Shutter work?
> - Purpose of the active grille shutter?

The active grille shutter assembly accomplishes three things:

1. Improves aerodynamic efficiency at higher speeds by forcing airflow over the hood,
2. Improves emissions by blocking airflow across the radiator at cold startup to speed up engine warm-up, and
3. increasing passenger comfort by blocking airflow across radiator to improve coolant heat retention.

As carmakers downsized engines to improve fuel economy they ran into a problem with cabin heat. Smaller engines require less coolant, so in cold weather that coolant cooling couldn’t provide enough heat to warm cabin occupants and keep the engine at full operating temperature. To remedy the situation, car makers install an active grille shutter assembly in front of the radiator to reduce airflow and increase coolant heat retention.

When the active grille shutter operates the ECU controls the active grille shutter operation. It closes the shutter when it detects low cooling and A/C loads the engine cooling system doesn’t need high airflow. In some makes, the shutter is controlled by the fuel pump control module. In other words, high fuel pump loads automatically dictate high speed and that opens the shutters.

The shutters remain closed at engine startup and in cold weather.

Ref: https://ricksfreeautorepairadvice.com/active-grille-shutter/

Comment: You should have just edited your original post. You also should reference your information if pulling it from another source. I'll put the link in this answer and delete the other one for you.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question because it is just generic information. I am looking for information specific to the 2011 Chevy Cruze Eco. On the eco, active grill shutters do not block the main opening on the radiator, but a smaller grill closer to the road. It is for air damning purposes however I am looking for specifics about when the grill opens and closes(temp ranges) and preferably some mechanical diagram what the location of the motor and wiring which I don't have in any aftermarket manual. On the eco, its controled by the fuel pump control module in the trunk.